# How can I get back to the normal task manager screen?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-manager

I'm using Windows Server 2008R2 on a machine. Suddenly the task manager switched to the screen below and I don't find a way to get back to the normal task amanger.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: At the top, there should be tabs. You've selected the Users tab. If you sellect Applications or Processes, it should bring back the familiar sight.

Comment: That is my problem I see no tabs on top (tried even to log out and in again but the same).  Also "alt" opens no menu

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the entire window, including titlebar? maybe the window is just moved to above the screen edge.

Comment: the problem is that IS the entire window (I have no menu bar and no title bar shown. else it would have been easy. The screenshot was made with a tool so tha tI could paste everything that is the window without fearing that parts are left out).

Comment: @LPChip updated the picture so that its clearer

Comment: That is really weird. I have no explaination for this. The only thing I can think of, is the act of a program to do this, with the option of changing this state by a keypress.

Comment: @Thomas, just double click on the border of the task manager, the task manager should be back to normal

Comment: @zalmy tnx that was it. I knew it was something easy but didnt find any info there. Tnx (if you post it as an answer I will accept it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double click on the border of the Task Manager and Task Manager will have the tabs and menus.

Thank you

Comment: The interesting thing is the same thing is what creates the situation. Thus double click on the border and the situation is created (only the currently shown tab is shown and no menu,... like in the screenshot I have posted). Doubleclick on the border like in the answer solves the problem again.